# Why can't I change my password and login with Skype?

Tags: passwords, skype-for-web

Why can't I change my password and login with Skype? I keep getting the following problem:
[image: Skype button isn't active]

As you can see, the button is still "grayed-out" and even though both password combinations are the same, it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not being snarky - have you tried another browser? Perhaps it's not rendering quite right in Chrome but it might work in IE or Firefox.